# How to configure a VLAN for all its client to get stateful IPv6 through a DHCPv6 server in the network on a Cisco C891F router?

Tags: cisco, vlan, ipv6, dhcpv6

Alright, so I've been trying this without any luck the whole day.

How to configure a VLAN for all its client to get stateful IPv6 through a DHCPv6 server in the network on a Cisco C891F router?

My current configuration abbreviated with IPv6 relevant stuff only:

```
 ipv6 unicast-routing
 ipv6 cef
 !
 interface GigabitEthernet8
  description Internet
  ipv6 address 2800:160:1F88:1::2/126
  ipv6 enable
 !     
 interface Vlan1
  description LAN
  ipv6 address 2800:160:1F88::1/64
  ipv6 enable
  ipv6 nd prefix 2600:160:1F88::/64 300 300 no-autoconfig
  ipv6 nd managed-config-flag
  ipv6 nd ra lifetime 9000
 !
 ipv6 route ::/0 2800:160:1F88:1::1
```

DHCPv6 is at 2800:160:1F88:12 on a Windows Server 2016.
As a sidenote DHCP works correctly on it.

I just cannot get it to work, clients are still getting autoconfig through SLAAC, they do not even get the Nameservers configured at the DHCPv6 server.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ipv6 nd prefix 2800:160:1F88::/64 no-advertise
```

Solved it.